# WPF DataGrid lose focus on button click

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

I'm using MVVM for my project, basicaly I have a DataGrid with a number of columns binded to my ViewModel's properties. I have for each row a button with a Validate function which takes the values from the UI and performs various checks. I'm having troubles with updating the model's property value, I would love it to be updated when I click on the button... At the moment I can update it by hitting the enter key or clicking on another element on the page, but if I change the value of the cell and click on the button right after the value won't be updated.

At the moment my DataGrid looks like this (I'm using DataGridExtensions to add a filter to the columns and handle the lost focus event):

```
<DataGrid  dgx:Tools.ForceCommitOnLostFocus="True" dgx:DataGridFilter.IsAutoFilterEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Subscriptions}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Visibility="{Binding HasRecords, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectedItem="{Binding Records}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" dgx:DataGridFilterColumn.IsFilterVisible="False"  HeaderStyle="{StaticResource Header}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Button Content="Validate" Focusable="True" Width="100" Margin="5" Tag="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource SimpleButtonTheme}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding DataContext.CheckSubCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="InvoiceOwner" Binding="{Binding InvoiceOwner}" dgx:DataGridFilterColumn.Template="{StaticResource MultipleChoiceFilter}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource Header}"/>
</DataGrid>
```

My aim is, as said earlier, be able to edit the cell value, click on the button "Validate" and have the value updated without having a middle step (clicking away/hitting enter on the keyboard / etc...)